# Como ordenar lista duplamente encadeada sem afetar a lista original?

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Olá!

Até o momento, já consegui realizar a implementação de todos os métodos da lista, inclusive o de ordenação. Porém, o problema é que ao ordenar, mesmo criando uma nova lista e fazendo essa receber a lista que deveria ser ordenada como parâmetro, ao ordenar, todas as duas listas são afetadas.

Imagino que isso esteja ocorrendo por eu estar passando a referência (endereço na memória) da lista original, seria isso? Se for isso, como contornar?

Postarei trechos de códigos mais relevantes, caso sintam falta de mais algum só avisar que eu edito.

**Chamando os Métodos na Main:**

```
            case 6: 
                EstruturaDeDados.MostrarCandidatos(LDE, "Relatório Por Ordem de Inscrição");
                break;
            case 7: 
                EstruturaDeDados.ClassificarCandidados(LDE);
                break;
            default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Opção inválida!","Advertência",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
```

**Método responsável por exibir qualquer lista passada como parâmetro:**

```
public static void MostrarCandidatos(EstruturaDeDados _LDE, String tela) 
{
    No UA = new No();               // Usuário Atual  
    String relatorio = "";              // Relatório
    String linha_divisora = "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    int c = 0;                      // Contador
    UA = _LDE.getInicioDaLista();
    String tituloDasTelas = "Sistema de Classificação " + tela;

    if (!_LDE.isEmpty()) {
        relatorio += linha_divisora;
        relatorio += "                                                                                                                                                  Relatório de Candidatos                   \n";
        relatorio += linha_divisora;
        relatorio += "|                   Posição                   |                    Código                   |                   Nome                   |                   Nascimento                   |                   Pontuação                   |                   Renda                   |\n";
        relatorio += linha_divisora;

        while (UA != null) 
        {                
              relatorio +="|"+StringUtils.center(Integer.toString(c), 52)+
                      "|"+StringUtils.center(Integer.toString(UA.getDadosDoCandidato().getCodCandidato()), 50)+
                      "|"+StringUtils.center(" "+UA.getDadosDoCandidato().getNomeCandidato(), 40)+
                      "|"+StringUtils.center(UA.getDadosDoCandidato().getDataNascimentoCandidato(), 52)+
                      "|"+StringUtils.center(Double.toString(UA.getDadosDoCandidato().getPontuacaoCandidato()), 52)+
                      "|"+StringUtils.center(Double.toString(UA.getDadosDoCandidato().getRendaCandidato()), 45)+"|\n";

                       UA = UA.getProximo();
                       c++;
        }
        relatorio += linha_divisora;
    }

    if(!relatorio.equals(""))
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,relatorio,tituloDasTelas,JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Não existe(m) usuário(s) cadastrado(s)!",tituloDasTelas,JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

}
```

**Método responsável por realizar a ordenação:**

```
public static void ClassificarCandidados(EstruturaDeDados LDEClassificados) 
{

    Candidato Candidato_AUX;
    No UA = LDEClassificados.getInicioDaLista();
    No PU = LDEClassificados.getInicioDaLista().getProximo();

    int length = LDEClassificados.getQuantidadeCandidatos();

    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < length - (i+1); j++) {
            if (UA.getDadosDoCandidato().getPontuacaoCandidato() > PU.getDadosDoCandidato().getPontuacaoCandidato()) {

                Candidato_AUX = UA.getDadosDoCandidato();
                UA.setDadosDoCandidato(PU.getDadosDoCandidato());
                PU.setDadosDoCandidato(Candidato_AUX);
            }
             UA = UA.getProximo();
             PU = PU.getProximo();
        }
        UA = LDEClassificados.getInicioDaLista();
        PU = LDEClassificados.getInicioDaLista().getProximo();
    }
    EstruturaDeDados.MostrarCandidatos(LDEClassificados, "Relatório Por Ordem de Pontuação");

}
```

**Classe Estrutura de Dados:**

```
public class EstruturaDeDados {

/*-----------------------------------
         ATRIBUTOS DA CLASSE
  -----------------------------------*/


private No inicio_lista;
private int quantidade_candidatos;
private No final_lista;
private EstruturaDeDados LDEClassificados, LDESuplentes;
/*-----------------------------------
         CONSTRUTOR DA CLASSE
  -----------------------------------*/



/*-----------------------------------
        MÉTODOS get E set DA CLASSE
  -----------------------------------*/

public No getInicioDaLista()
{
    return inicio_lista;
}
public void setInicioDaLista(No _IL)
{
    inicio_lista = _IL;
}

public int getQuantidadeCandidatos()
{
    return quantidade_candidatos;
}
public void setQuantidadeCandidatos(int _QC)
{
    quantidade_candidatos = _QC;
}

public No getFinalDaLista()
{
    return final_lista;
}
public void setFinalDaLista(No _FL)
{
    final_lista = _FL;
}

/*-----------------------------------
           MÉTODOS DA CLASSE
  -----------------------------------*/
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return this.getQuantidadeCandidatos() == 0;
}

public void InicializarLista()
{
    this.setInicioDaLista(null);
    this.setQuantidadeCandidatos(0);
    this.setFinalDaLista(null);
}

public boolean  InserirCandidato(int _p, int _cc, String _nc, String _dnc, double _pc, double _rm) 
{

    if (_p < 0 || _p > this.getQuantidadeCandidatos()) {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        No novoNo = new No(_cc, _nc, _dnc, _pc, _rm);

        // Caso 1 - Lista Vazia
        if (this.isEmpty()) 
        {
            this.setInicioDaLista(novoNo);
            this.setFinalDaLista(novoNo);
        }
        else
        {
            // Caso 2 - Posição = 0
            if (_p == 0) {

                // Novo nó aponta como próximo o nó contido no inicio da lista.
                novoNo.setProximo(this.getInicioDaLista());

                // Nó do inicio da lista passa a apontar como anterior o novo nó.
                this.getInicioDaLista().setAnterior(novoNo);

                // Lista recebe como inicio da lista o novo nó.
                this.setInicioDaLista(novoNo);
            }

            // Caso 3 - Posição = Quantidade de Usuários
            if (_p == this.getQuantidadeCandidatos()) {

                novoNo.setAnterior(this.getFinalDaLista());
                this.getFinalDaLista().setProximo(novoNo);
                this.setFinalDaLista(novoNo);
            }
            else
            {
                // Caso 4 - [Posição > 0] && [Posição < Quantidade de Usuários]

                // UA -> Usuário Atual
                // PU -> Próximo Usuário
                // C  -> Contador 

                No UA, PU;

                if (_p <= (this.getQuantidadeCandidatos()/2)) {

                    int C = 0;

                    UA = this.getInicioDaLista();
                    while (C < _p-1) {                            
                        UA = UA.getProximo();
                        C++;
                    }

                    PU = UA.getProximo();

                    UA.setProximo(novoNo);
                    PU.setAnterior(novoNo);

                    novoNo.setAnterior(UA);
                    novoNo.setProximo(PU);

                }
                else
                {
                    UA = this.getFinalDaLista();
                    int C = this.getQuantidadeCandidatos()-1;

                    while (C > _p) {                            
                        UA = UA.getAnterior();
                        C--;
                    }
                    PU = UA.getAnterior();

                    PU.setProximo(novoNo);
                    UA.setAnterior(novoNo);

                    novoNo.setAnterior(PU);
                    novoNo.setProximo(UA);
                }
            }
        }
        this.setQuantidadeCandidatos(this.getQuantidadeCandidatos()+1);
        return true;

    }
}

public boolean ExcluirCandidato(int _p) 
{

    if (_p < 0 && _p > this.getQuantidadeCandidatos()) {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        if (this.getQuantidadeCandidatos() == 1) {
            this.InicializarLista();
        }
        else
        {
            No UA; // Usuário Atual

            if (_p == 0) {

               UA = this.getInicioDaLista().getProximo();
               UA.setAnterior(null);

               this.getInicioDaLista().setProximo(null);
               this.setInicioDaLista(UA); 
            }
            else
            {
                if (_p == this.getQuantidadeCandidatos()-1) {

                    UA = this.getFinalDaLista().getAnterior();
                    UA.setProximo(null);

                    this.getFinalDaLista().setAnterior(null);
                    this.setFinalDaLista(UA);
                }
                else
                {
                    int C; // Contador
                    No PU;

                    if (_p <= (this.getQuantidadeCandidatos()/2)) {

                        C = 0;
                        UA = this.getInicioDaLista();

                        while(C < _p-1)
                        {
                            UA = UA.getProximo();
                            C++;
                        }

                        PU = UA.getProximo().getProximo();

                        UA.getProximo().setAnterior(null);
                        UA.getProximo().setProximo(null);

                        UA.setProximo(PU);
                        PU.setAnterior(UA);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        C = this.getQuantidadeCandidatos()-1;
                        UA = this.getFinalDaLista();

                        while (C > _p) {                                
                            UA = UA.getAnterior();
                            C--;
                        }
                        PU = UA.getAnterior().getAnterior();

                        UA.getAnterior().setAnterior(null);
                        UA.getAnterior().setProximo(null);

                        UA.setAnterior(PU);
                        PU.setProximo(UA);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    this.setQuantidadeCandidatos(this.getQuantidadeCandidatos()-1);
    return true;
}

public No PesquisarCandidato(int _cdc) 
{
    No UA = this.getInicioDaLista();

    while (UA != null) {       

        if (UA.getDadosDoCandidato().getCodCandidato() == _cdc) 
            return UA;
            UA = UA.getProximo();

    }
    return null;
}

public static void MostrarCandidatos(EstruturaDeDados _LDE, String tela) 
{
    No UA = new No();               // Usuário Atual  
    String relatorio = "";              // Relatório
    String linha_divisora = "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    int c = 0;                      // Contador
    UA = _LDE.getInicioDaLista();
    String tituloDasTelas = "Sistema de Classificação " + tela;

    if (!_LDE.isEmpty()) {
        relatorio += linha_divisora;
        relatorio += "                                                                                                                                                  Relatório de Candidatos                   \n";
        relatorio += linha_divisora;
        relatorio += "|                   Posição                   |                    Código                   |                   Nome                   |                   Nascimento                   |                   Pontuação                   |                   Renda                   |\n";
        relatorio += linha_divisora;

        while (UA != null) 
        {                
              relatorio +="|"+StringUtils.center(Integer.toString(c), 52)+
                      "|"+StringUtils.center(Integer.toString(UA.getDadosDoCandidato().getCodCandidato()), 50)+
                      "|"+StringUtils.center(" "+UA.getDadosDoCandidato().getNomeCandidato(), 40)+
                      "|"+StringUtils.center(UA.getDadosDoCandidato().getDataNascimentoCandidato(), 52)+
                      "|"+StringUtils.center(Double.toString(UA.getDadosDoCandidato().getPontuacaoCandidato()), 52)+
                      "|"+StringUtils.center(Double.toString(UA.getDadosDoCandidato().getRendaCandidato()), 45)+"|\n";

                       UA = UA.getProximo();
                       c++;
        }
        relatorio += linha_divisora;
    }

    if(!relatorio.equals(""))
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,relatorio,tituloDasTelas,JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Não existe(m) usuário(s) cadastrado(s)!",tituloDasTelas,JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

}

public boolean AlterarDadosCandidato(int _cc, String _nc, String _dnc, double _pc, double _rm) 
{
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

public boolean AlterarDadosCandidato(No Candidato) 
{
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

public static void ClassificarCandidados(EstruturaDeDados LDEClassificados) 
{

    Candidato Candidato_AUX;
    No UA = LDEClassificados.getInicioDaLista();
    No PU = LDEClassificados.getInicioDaLista().getProximo();

    int length = LDEClassificados.getQuantidadeCandidatos();

    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < length - (i+1); j++) {
            if (UA.getDadosDoCandidato().getPontuacaoCandidato() > PU.getDadosDoCandidato().getPontuacaoCandidato()) {

                Candidato_AUX = UA.getDadosDoCandidato();
                UA.setDadosDoCandidato(PU.getDadosDoCandidato());
                PU.setDadosDoCandidato(Candidato_AUX);
            }
             UA = UA.getProximo();
             PU = PU.getProximo();
        }
        UA = LDEClassificados.getInicioDaLista();
        PU = LDEClassificados.getInicioDaLista().getProximo();
    }
    EstruturaDeDados.MostrarCandidatos(LDEClassificados, "Relatório Por Ordem de Pontuação");

}

public void ListarClassificados() 
{
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

public void ListarSuplentes() 
{
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}
```

}

Comment: Ramon, coloca a classe EstruturaDeDados também. Vai ajudar na resposta.

Comment: Ela é um pouco grande, mas coloquei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver esse problema, eu segui os seguintes passos:

1. Criar um ArrayList do tipo dos dados que nesse caso é Candidato.

   ```
   ArrayList<Candidato> copiaLDE = new ArrayList();

   EstruturaDeDados LDEClassificados = new EstruturaDeDados();
   ```
2. Feito isso, em um laço de repetição, adiciono todos os candidatos no ArrayList.

   ```
   while (UA != null) {            
       copiaLDE.add(UA.getDadosDoCandidato());
       UA = UA.getProximo();
   }
   ```
3. Agora basta utilizar o próprio método "InserirCandidato" percorrendo a lista criada que o problema estará resolvido.

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
       LDEClassificados.InserirCandidato(i, copiaLDE.get(i));
   }
   ```